# R Eliyahu Guttmacher on the Mishnah

Tags: jewish-books, commentaries, mishna

Does anyone know where I can read R Eliyahu Guttmacher's chiddushim on the Mishnah (specifically, Keilim)? [Apparently](https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/guttmacher-elijah) published in the Romm Talmud edition, but I've not managed to identify this online. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R. Eliyahu Guttmacher's commentary on *mishnah* is printed at the back of the standard Romm edition of Mishnah (not Talmud).

For Kelim, see e.g. [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9686&st=&pgnum=529&hilite=) - the commentary is entitled *hiddushei ha-gaon rabbenu eliyahu mi-graditz ([Grodzisk Wielkopolski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grodzisk_Wielkopolski))*.